# Doubt in the proof of a limits theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I was revising the limits chapter from my maths reference book for IIT exam.
When I gone through the proof of a theorem, a very serious doubt came into my mind.
The theorem is as shown in the attached image,
[The theorem and it's proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrCxo.jpg)

My doubt:
Theorem statement is,by meaning, that if $lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ and $lim_{x\to a} g(x)$ exists then the $lim_{x\to a}(f(x)+g(x))$ also exists.
In the last line of the proof they've used the theorem itself as if $lim_{x\to a}[f(x)+g(x)]$ and $lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ exists then $lim_{x\to a} {[f(x)+g(x)]-f(x)}$ also exists.
How can we prove a theorem by using itself in the proof??
If there is any misconception or mistake in my thought, then pls correct me.

Comment: The photograph is not of "the limit theorem".  The photograph is of a corollary to that theorem.  Presumably, the limit theorem says something like (with details omitted, and probably with similar statements about addition, multiplication, and division (as long as the limit in the denominator is not zero)) "If $\lim A$ exists and $\lim B$ exists, $\lim (A-B)$ exists and $\lim (A-B) = \lim A - \lim B$."

Comment: Note that, if both the limits $$lim_{x\to a}f(x)$$ and $$lim_{x\to a}g(x)$$ exists then $$lim_{x\to a}(f(x)+g(x)) $$ must exist, it's by property of limits. The fact that the individual limits exists is important because if it diverges then the above property doesn't hold true. The same fact is used in the theorem. In the last line $f(x)$ was added and subtracted to $g(x)$ in this limit, $$lim_{x\to a}g(x)$$ so as to split this according to property I mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My doubt: Theorem statement is,by meaning, that if lim f(x) and lim
> g(x) exists then the lim (f(x)+g(x)) also exists.

No. The text does not say that. It says, **if**
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow c}(f(x)+g(x)) \\
$$
**and**
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x)
$$
exist, **then**
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow c}g(x)
$$
must exist.

> In the last line of the proof they've used the theorem itself as if
> lim[f(x)+g(x)] and lim f(x) exists then lim {[f(x)+g(x)]-f(x)} also
> exists. How can we proove a theorem by using itself in the proof?? If
> there is any misconception or mistake in my thought, then pls correct
> me.

The theorem that *you think* the text has used in a circular manner is
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow c}(f(x)+g(x))=\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x)+\lim_{x\rightarrow c}g(x)
$$
That is the sum rule. They're not proving *this* theorem. They're doing exactly what you've highlighted, i.e, if
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x)=L \text{ (which is given to exist)}
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow c}(f(x)+g(x))=K \text{ (which is also given to exist)}
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow c}g(x)=M \text{ (which we have to prove exists)}
$$
then using the sum rule we know that
$$
K=L+M
$$
and hence
$$
M=K-L
$$
which not only proves $M$ exists, but also gives it's value.